# 「これくらいで」 whats the grammatical purpose that で has here?

Tags: particles, particle-で

[image: Yotsuba&]

Googling around for that particular phrase pretty much leads only to a song これくらいで歌う or it's use with の as in これくらいの塩で充分だ. I have a sneaking suspicion it may be related to the adverbial usage of これくらい, but not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Among a series of definitions of particle で, which you will find in your dictionary, this is a **で denoting reasons / causalities**.

Your example, though the wording seems to be kind of culture-specific and I find it hard to traslate, may roughly mean something like "It' funny she is acting like a senior only for *these reasons*" (*these reasons* depending on the context) or similar.

Another example:

> [試合]{しあい}は[雨]{あめ}で[中止]{ちゅうし}になりました。 The game has been called off due to the rain.
>   これくらいの[小雨]{こさめ}で中止にしてほしくない。 I don't want it called off just for this light rain.

If you skip "light rain" from the latter then:

> これくらいで中止にしてほしくない。

Comment: So これくらい doesn't modify お姉さん to say something like '(act like) this much of an older sister/senior' but modifies some unknown reason? [The rest of the page](http://i.imgur.com/YmCQd69.png) explains the reason why she said that, but i'm still having trouble trying to fit a sentence like it would in your example. Am i trying to take it too literally?

Comment: Hmm...I am not really sure what you are having trouble with...but I will try.<br>
In the first place, これくらい modifies nothing, at least in the common usage of the term.
But これくらい refers to the quantity of some "adult behavior" she had shown previously, which must have been depicted in the pages before the page you cited (I don't think that page explains anything).

Comment: At any rate, to think logically, what the guy meant may be written like this: _"'Acting like a senior' just because of this much 'adult behavior' is laughable"_. Then, これくらいでお姉さんぶられてもな can be parsed as: _this much_ = これくらい / _because of_ = で / _'Act like a senior'_ = お姉さんぶる, with "adult behavior" (whatever it is) and "laughable" parts being dropped.<br>
Now my English ability is running out...Did it help you get rid of your trouble?